# How to use renderingMode with AsyncImage in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a button that I want to be an image that can change colors as needed (loading async). To do this, I thought I could do something like this:
I thought I could do something like this:

```html
Button(action: { doAction }) {
  AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "test.com")) { image in
    image
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      .renderingMode(.template)
  }
}
```

However, when I try to do this, I get a few errors:

"Cannot infer return type for closure with multiple statements"

"Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'TableRowBuilder' "

I'm not sure why these errors show up only when I add the "renderingMode" modifier. Everything works other than adding that. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderingMode` is a modifier that's only available on `Image`. The `aspectRatio` modifier returns a `View` so you can't use `Image`-specific modifiers after it.

The fix is easy, just move `aspectRatio` one line up, right after `resizable`.

Comment: moving renderingMode to be first fixed it for me. Thank you for explaining

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code.

1. You can’t apply image-specific modifiers, like `resizable(capInsets:resizingMode:)`, directly to an `AsyncImage`. Instead, apply them to the Image instance that your content closure gets when defining the view’s appearance. [From Apple developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage).

   ```
   Button(action: { print("Hello") }) {
       AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageURL)) { phase in
           if let image = phase.image {
               image
                   .resizable()
                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
           } else if phase.error != nil {
               Color.red // Indicates an error.
           } else {
               Color.blue // Acts as a placeholder.
           }
       }
       .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
   }

   //OR

   Button(action: { print("Hello") }) {
       AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageURL)) { image in
           image
               .resizable()
               .renderingMode(.template)
               .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
       } placeholder: {
           Color.clear
       }
       .frame(width: 100, height: 100) //Size of your button
   }
   ```
2. `renderingMode` modifier needs to be called on Image and you are calling it after `aspectRatio(contentMode:)`. Place it before and you are good to go.